# Elementos de los fragmentos no se muestran en pantalla

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estoy intentando crear un menú con 3 fragmentos, el problema es que no aparecen los elementos del layout de los fragmentos por pantalla, es decir, como si no existieran. Dejo por aquí el código de la activty principal y de uno de los fragmentos:

```
public class MenuPrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//Inicializar variable
MeowBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal);

    //Asigno variable
    bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    //Añadimos el item al menú
    bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(1, R.drawable.ic_fav));
    bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(2, R.drawable.ic_home));
    bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(3, R.drawable.ic_profile));

    bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.ShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShowItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {
            //Inicializamos fragmento
            Fragment fragment = null;

            //Chequeamos las condiciones
            switch (item.getId()) {
                case 1:
                    //Cuando el ID sea 1 inicializamos el FavFragment
                    fragment = new FavFragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Cuando el ID sea 2 inicalizamos el HomeFragment
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Cuando el ID sea 3 inicializamos el ProfileFragment
                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;
            }
            //Cargamos los fragmentos
            loadFragment(fragment);
        }
    });

    //Establecemos los contadores
    bottomNavigation.setCount(1,"10");
    //Establecemos homeFragment al iniciar activity
    bottomNavigation.show(2,true);

    bottomNavigation.setOnClickMenuListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {

            //Display toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "You clicked " + item.getId()
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    bottomNavigation.setOnReselectListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.ReselectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReselectItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {

            //Display toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "You reselected " + item.getId()
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //Reemplazamos fragmento
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);

}
```

Aquí dejo el del fragmento:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

> He puesto un toast al dar a cada menú y eso sí que funciona correctamente, pero los fragemtos siguen sin aparecer.

Mi objetivo es crear 3 fragmentos el cual al dar a otro, este se oculte y aparezca el nuevo.
Para poder comprobar que no funciona he creado un TextView en el fragmento principal para así saber si funciona o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas realizando el reemplazo del `Fragment` pero debes llamar también `.commit()`:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //Reemplazamos fragmento
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
            .commit(); //*Agregar!

}
```

La llamada `commit()` le indica al `FragmentManager` que todas las operaciones se han agregado a la transacción.